# Unable to send message in jms queue from webservice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, websphere, message-queue

I am facing some strange problem.It goes as below:
There are 2 EAR files which is using a common jar file.This jar file is responsible for putting message in the JMS queue.

Now from one EAR file,I am correctly able to send the message to queue and also retrieve it.But if I try from other EAR file there is no message sent to the JMS queue. There is no JMS or any other exception thrown while executing the code.

Could anyone please suggest me ,What could be the probable cause of this type of problem?

Could there be conflict with other JAR files.If yes what could be the probable JAR files related to it?

Comment: Each EAR have its copy of jar? Is it in a shared library? What version  the websphere you are using?

Comment: Are you sending them on the same bus?

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes each ear has its own copy of jar. I can even see the log message stating the message is sent which is printed after send() method. But the message is not present in the jms queue.

Comment: Hi Nikpon, Yes since both ear have a copy of same jar file. This jar file uses same connection and queue settings

Comment: if you follow the 'network' package exchange, does the message get to be sent? and just not received by jms broker?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in one of the EAR file, a JTA transaction is being started which then calls the JMS program which basically send and receive the message from the JMS queue. Since  the JTA transaction is not completed the message would not actually go to the queue and obviously it wont be received thus giving an exception.